# Getting wrong callback url for email confirmation in ASP NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, email, url, redirect, https

I am having very strange issue with my project. Everything works fine in debugging mode on localhost, but if I will publish it, I am getting the callback url without the https:// prefix. If user will click on the confirm button, some redirection tricky magic is happening as from url `http://www.detailandgo.co.uk/Identity/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=blablabla&code=foobar` I am getting `https://www.detailandgo.co.ukidentity/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=blablabla&code=foobar`.

As you can see, the url is correct, but I am missing the backslash between base url and "identity". If I will add it manually, everything works nicely. I was reading a lot about it, but haven't found any solution.

I am using ASP NET CORE 6 with Razor pages...

Thank you for all your suggestions and wishing you nice day!!

I've tried googleing a lot, having look in here at Stack Overflow, but haven't found any viable solution.

code which is generating the code:

```
_logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
                _userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                var test = Request.Scheme;
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);                   
                string encodedCallBackUrl = HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl);
                
                Email email = new Email();
                using (StreamReader reader = System.IO.File.OpenText(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + "/Email/index.html"))
                {
                    email.From = "info@detailandgo.co.uk";
                    email.Body = reader.ReadToEnd()
                        .Replace("{callbackUrl}", encodedCallBackUrl)
                        .Replace("{firstName}", Input.FirstName)
                        .Replace("{callbackBook}", Url.Page("/Index"));
                    email.IsHtml = true;
                    email.Subject = Input.FirstName + ", confirm your Detail&Go account";
                    email.To = Input.Email;
                }
```

Comment: please share your code which generates the url

Answer (score 0):

We can ensure the correctness of the URL through a certain format, as follows:

```
$"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}/{encodedCallbackUrl.TrimStart('/')}";
```

I have researched this issue, and I think this should be the workaround or could be the soultion.

Change below below code

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);                   
                string encodedCallBackUrl = HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl);
```

to

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);                   
                string encodedCallBackUrl = HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl);
                encodedCallBackUrl =$"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}/{encodedCallbackUrl.TrimStart('/')}";
```